# MySQL - Counting the number of patients

Tags: mysql

I have a `patient` table and a `reference` table as below

`patient` table

```
id         name
1          Doni
2          Doni
3          Doni
4          Tejo
5          Bambang
```

`reference` table

```
patient_id    refer_to_patient_id
1             2
2             3
3             null
```

refer_to_patient_id null means patient name Doni is referred to another Hospital but the Hospital it's referred to has not created a record.

And I need to count how many patient they have. Example above should return 3 patients as record id 1,2,3 is the same patient.
Patient name could be different even for the same patient since they are inputted from different hospitals.

PS: patient table is actually not patient entity, it's a medical record (EMR) and a hospital can refer a patient (or an EMR) to another hospital and it is counted as a single patient.

Comment: You reference table can be an entire tree structure for 1 patient? Can it be assured that there are no cycles in this structure?

Comment: Deduplicating patients from different EMR systems is an extraordinarily difficult problem to get right. It seems bizarre to attempt it without at least dates of birth to work with. Just sayin.

Comment: Dont worry about that. It's not that high tech critical emr for hospital system. It's just a simple data used by the medical society to do research. Yes there is date of birth actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While initially it seems like you need to resolve the full tree, I think that the question you're asking is as simple as

```
select 
  count(distinct pat.id) patients
from 
  patient pat 
  left outer join reference ref on pat.id = ref.patient_id
where 
  ref.patient_id is null;
```

That is, an `id` should only be counted when it does not have a map to another `id`. Put another way, any `id` value that does not have a mapped value is the end of the hierarchy.

Comment: hi, sorry I just edited the reference table. your solution almost worked until the reference has null in `refer_to_patient_id`. refer_to_patient_id null means patient name Doni is referred to another Hospital but the Hospital it's  referred to has not created a record.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to count that case as well. Just add another where so that it looks like `where ref.patient_id is null or ref.refer_to_patient_id is null`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT name)
FROM patient;
```

Comment: hi, sorry i forgot to tell you that value of name could be different even for the same patient.

Comment: I don't see how you could identify a DISTINCT patient. Based on your description, there is no unique identifier or combination of identifiers that would make DISTINCTION between 1   Doni and 2   Doni

Comment: that's why there is `reference` table